# add constraint rule pyomo

Tags: constraints, rules, pyomo

I have been trying to create a constraint based on a certain condition that is the binary output of my function ('Check_Condition'). The type of constraint is just a basic "conflicting" constraint to avoid that two conflicting variables are chosen. The constraint seems to be ignored (I included the print statement as a check), although I do not get any error. Here is the code. I do not want to use nested loops as they considerably slow down the code. Thanks!

```
model.n = RangeSet(n_operations)
model.triangular = Set(within=model.n * model.n, filter=lambda i, j: j < i)

def con(model, i, j):
        if Check_Condition(operations[i],operations[j])==1:
            print('added constraint')
            return model.x[i] + model.x[j] <= 1
        else:
            return Constraint.Skip

model.OverlapConst = Constraint(model.triangular, rule=con)
```

Comment: Could you share the `Check_Condition` function? What is stored in `operations`?

Comment: Hello Bethany, thanks for the reply. "Check_Condition" compares some values contained in operations and determines whether the two operations are conflict or not by simply giving as an output 0/1

Comment: Does the value returned by `Check_Condition` or the values in `operations` depend on values of Pyomo `Var` components?

Comment: No they don't. I was actually able to code the same constraint by using a nested loop for i and j. However, since it is taking considerable time to add it to the optimization model, I wanted to try an alternative way.

Comment: What do you mean by "the constraint seems to be ignored"? If you run the command `model.OverlapConst.pprint()` does the constraint look correct? How are you solving your model?